# Why does every post here gets downvoted and disregarded?

Tags: discussion

Why does every post here gets downvoted and disregarded, even though many users here are not even professional physicists?

Much condescension and feeling of self value, for someone as partial, don't you think?

Comment: The comments on this question appeared to be unproductive, so I've deleted them.

Comment: @DavidZ Unproductive? I put so much effort into them and I think the OP ended up clearly explaining the nature of their complaint and we reached (I think) some kind of acceptance or understanding. I think that was completely productive or I'm a rubber duck

Comment: @Jim Plenty of personal attacks, as far as I can tell. Plus from what I see of his comment history he clearly didn't come to an understanding here. Can't say much more than that.

Answer (score 10):

A quick glance at the question page or the front page shows more upvoted than downvoted posts.

Physics SE has high standards for questions (and answers) but my observation is that most users are hesitant to use downvotes, with one expception. The exception is posts that violate the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). Especially second and subsequent posts by the same user.

Please understand that this site is of and by physicists<sup>1</sup> and while we welcome beginners to our group, we expect them to be willing to take part *as* physicists.

You seem, to have gotten a mistaken impression of what we do here and what the site is for. Perhaps just observing for a few days might make things a little more clear.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some professionals, some future professionals and some plain old amateurs, but all physicsist or putting on a convincing impression thereof.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a sympathetic comment, not an answer, but it grew too long for the comment box.

In the main, there are lots and lots of very good questions that get upvoted and stay around, and there's a healthy population of poor questions that get downvoted and removed. Any system for differentiating the two will make mistakes sometimes. That's okay. It's just a website.

There certainly are days when the confines beyond which questions are closed as "not physics" are so narrow that it baffles me; I've been tempted to retaliate by leaving close votes on good questions that say "this question is about the motion of charged particles in electromagnetic fields and not about physics." (I probably wouldn't do something so petty, but closures like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128968/44126) put me in the mood.)

Take the OP's question about [temperatures at different latitudes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96229/44126). There's a very simple physical explanation why you get more insolation and low latitudes than at high latitudes — the angle of incidence — and it appeared in an answer just two hours after the question was asked. I agree with the sentiment at that question that meteorology and climate science are broad topics which are not properly a subset of physics, and the question was muddled by the asker's misconceptions. But on the whole it was probably a question that could have stayed.

Comment: Hi rob, this is just a minor point concerning the [specific question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128968/2451) you mentioned and not related to this meta discussion per se: If you think a question should be re-opened, vote to reopen so that it enters the review-queue.

Comment: @Qmechanic Whoops, thanks, I did the one but not the other.